# How to assign default value to lookup field in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

In Lightning component we have used aura id to set value.

```
Lightning Component

<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Account">                                    
 <lightning:inputField variant="label-hidden" aura:id="userId" label="Users" fieldName="SampleUser__c"  value=""/>
</lightning:recordEditForm> 

component.find('userId').set('v.value', selectedUserId);
```

How to set the value to a lookup field in LWC. Please advise on this.

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account" >
       <lightning-input-field field-name="SampleUser__c" onchange={onUserChange} >  
      </lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Option 1: Directly identify the element and set value: (**Preferred**)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <lightning-button label="Set Acc id" onclick={setAccid}></lightning-button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">
            <lightning-messages>
            </lightning-messages>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName">
            </lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName">
            </lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field data-accid field-name="AccountId">
            </lightning-input-field>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
setAccid() {
    this.template.querySelector('[data-accid]').value = '00128000009j45sAAA';
}
```

**you can invoke `setAccid` whenever you need. Advantage here is, you need not maintained tracked properties like below option.**

---

Option 2: You can use `value` directly. Note that LWC is not 2-way binding, so value is used only for default. This is useful when you want to set values in multiple fields through an object property.

HTML:

```
<lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" value={accid}>
        </lightning-input-field>
```

JS:

```
@track accid;

setAccid(){
    this.accid = '00128000009j45sAAA';
}
```

You can invoke `setAccid` whenever you want to set the `accid`.